# Left outer join, find all from left having no occurrences in right table, mysql

Tags: mysql

Having two tables, a mapping and a data table, I want to find all mappings that don't have any associated data

For example:

```
     map                 data
============        ===============
mapId | name         mapId | value
------------        ---------------
  1      A             1       x
  2      B             1       y
  3      C             2       z
```

For this case I want to return the mapId 3/C, since it exists in the map table but does not have a record in the data table

How can I query this? I've tried every combo of group and having and where I can think of, the closest I got was

```
SELECT map.name
FROM map
LEFT OUTER JOIN data on data.mapId = map.mapId
GROUP BY data.mapId
HAVING max(data.value) is null
```

I also tried grouping by map.mapId, and having count(data.dataId) = 0, all to no avail. NO matter how I set it up I'm getting either some maps that do have data, or not getting some maps that don't have data.

Comment: anti-join pattern ... ditch the GROUP BY and HAVING clauses, add a WHERE with a condition that returns only rows that have a NULL value of data.mapId ...`WHERE data.mapid IS NULL`  and then what gets returned are the rows from map that didn't have a match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to group, a left join is enough:

```
SELECT map.*
FROM map LEFT JOIN data 
on data.mapId = map.mapId
WHERE data.mapId is null
```

Also another way to do it with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT map.*
FROM map  
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM data 
  WHERE data.mapId = map.mapId
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to `group by` to achieve this. There can be multiple rows for one `mapId` in data do I added `distinct`.

```
select
    distinct m.mapId, m.name
from map m
left join data d
    on m.mapId = d.mapId
where d.mapId is null
```